# How do I rotate a curve?

Tags: geometry, parametric-functions, rotation

I have a circular segment defined as:

```
    ParametricPlot[5 {Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}, {ϕ, -0.2, 0.8}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

which I have to rotate around point `5 {Sin[0.8], 1 - Cos[0.8]}` for `0.3` radians and I don't know how to do it.

I tried with `Rotate` which is not what I needed, because it rotates the whole graphics - axes included. I only want to rotate the circular segment. I had a strong feeling that I should use `RotationMatrix` and so I tried that too:

```
ParametricPlot[5*RotationMatrix[0.3].{Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}, {ϕ, -0.2, 0.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

but here the output is the plot rotated around the origin. But If I try to rotate around a certain point

```
RotationMatrix[0.3,5 {Sin[.8], 1 - Cos[.8]}]
```

I get an error saying that the dimensions are wrong. What can I do to rotate the curve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's actually a built in function `RotationTransform` for that:

```
rotation = RotationTransform[0.3, fixedpoint];

ParametricPlot[{5 {Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}, 
  rotation[5 {Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}]}, {ϕ, -0.2, 0.8}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 6):

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d), to rotate about a fixed point, you first translate that point to the origin, apply the rotation matrix, then reverse the translation.

```
rotateparametric[parfunc_, fixedpoint_, angle_] := 
  RotationMatrix[angle].(parfunc - fixedpoint) + fixedpoint;

 ParametricPlot[{5 {Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}, 
   rotateparametric[5 {Sin[ϕ], 1 - Cos[ϕ]}, fixedpoint,0.3]},
   {ϕ, -0.2, 0.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, big time! This works nicely!

Comment: @skrat I just edited it to make a function, so that you can easily do this to any 2D parametric function.